# Consulta Case con un isnumeric en SQLSERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

bueno tengo un pequeño problema las cosultas case nunca me funcionan lo suficientemente bien.
Me paso que un campo que antes guardaba el nombre de un plan, ahora guarda el id del plan.
Necesito hacer una consulta por fechas que en el sp que antes funcionaba.

Entonces necesito que decida si va a buscar el nombre del plan normal o lo va a buscar desde el id.

esta es la linea de codigo exacta del error

```
(select P.[Plan] from dbo.[Plan] P where V.[Plan] = CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(V.[Plan]) = 1 THEN P.[Id] ELSE P.[Plan] END) As Planes
```

y este es casi todo el sp (omito alguno datos por que es muy largo:

```
                SELECT V.[Id]
                ,V.[Colonia]
                ,V.[DelegacionMunicipio]
                ,V.[EstadoVivienda]
                ,V.[Domicilio_DireccionCompleta]
                ,V.[EntreCalles]
                ,V.[ReferenciasCasa]
                ,V.[NumeroContacto1]
                ,V.[NumeroContacto2]
                ,V.[ID_INE(CURP)] as ID_INE
                ,V.[Email]
                ,V.[NIP]
                ,V.[IdVenta]
                ,(select P.[Plan] from dbo.[Plan] P where V.[Plan] = CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(V.[Plan]) = 1 THEN P.[Id] ELSE P.[Plan] END) As Planes
                ,V.[Plan]
                ,V.[MetodoEntrega]
                
            FROM [dbo].[Ventas] V WITH (NOLOCK)
            INNER  JOIN [dbo].[EstadoVenta] E WITH (NOLOCK) ON V.Estado = E.Id
            WHERE TmStmp >= @FechaInicio
            AND TmStmp <= @FechaFin
```

entonces no se si lo estoy haciendo bien, o como deberia hacer, espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: y cuál es el mensaje de error?

Comment: dice que no puede convertir (cualquier plan varchar) en un int

Comment: el punto es que si funciona cuando solo filtro fechas que tengan ese dato en numerico, pero si llega a ver cualquier dato de texto marca error

Comment: Creo que no está de más comentar que no es buena idea tener un único campo donde antes guardabas el nombre del plan y ahora guardas un ID. Es decir, al final puedes hacer funcionar las cosas, pero no es el mejor diseño. Entiendo que la idea haya podido cambiar a medio camino, eso es bastante normal, pero podrías haber creado un nuevo campo que SIEMPRE tenga el ID y hacer un update para llenarlo con los ID's de los planes que estaban guardados en el viejo campo. Finalmente eliminar el campo anterior. Al final, quedas con algo más usable y consistente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el tipo de dato de `Id` es `int` y el de `Plan` es varchar. El resultado de una expresión `CASE` debe ser de un único tipo de datos, entonces no puedes simplemente decir que en algunos casos sea `Id` y en otros `Plan`.

Una alternativa es la siguiente:

```
SELECT V.[Id]
                ,V.[Colonia]
                ,V.[DelegacionMunicipio]
                ,V.[EstadoVivienda]
                ,V.[Domicilio_DireccionCompleta]
                ,V.[EntreCalles]
                ,V.[ReferenciasCasa]
                ,V.[NumeroContacto1]
                ,V.[NumeroContacto2]
                ,V.[ID_INE(CURP)] as ID_INE
                ,V.[Email]
                ,V.[NIP]
                ,V.[IdVenta]
                ,(select P.[Plan] from dbo.[Plan] P where V.[Plan] = CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(V.[Plan]) = 1 THEN CONVERT(varchar(100),P.[Id]) ELSE P.[Plan] END) As Planes
                ,V.[Plan]
                ,V.[MetodoEntrega]
                
            FROM [dbo].[Ventas] V WITH (NOLOCK)
            INNER  JOIN [dbo].[EstadoVenta] E WITH (NOLOCK) ON V.Estado = E.Id
            WHERE TmStmp >= @FechaInicio
            AND TmStmp <= @FechaFin
```

Comment: Me funciono perfecto, muchas gracias!!!